# Rows sequence in AWS DMS using RDS as source

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration, dms

I am new to AWS DMS and currently setting up DMS full load to migrate from RDS to KDS. I want to know if AWS DMS preserve the rows sequence (not sure if RDS maintains any rows sequencing at its side on the basis of update/creation timestamp)?

Answer (score 0):

On PostgreSQL, AWS DMS itself does not preserve Sequence.

However, there is an [open source snippet](https://github.com/sinwoobang/dms-psql-post-data) to help your case.
It generates SQL that makes Sequence on your target DB.